# Redraw GMapMarker using internal timer

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I have a custom GMapMarker class that draws a simple image to map... How to make that image to change its properties (lets say blink) in interval of 500ms?

Using GMapControl.Invalidate() will cause to redraw my marker and entire map! Which will cause unregulated blinking, since this method OnRedraw() is called every time a map property is changed! (When map is in idle this method is not called!)

My solution would require to use internal Timer like in my sample, but don't know how to redraw my images from Timer elapsed function.

```
namespace GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers {
public class GMarkerNode : GMapMarker {

    public Image Image { get; set; }
    private Timer Timer;

    public GMarkerNode(PointLatLng p) : base(p)
    {
        Timer = new Timer()
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = 500
        };
        Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // How to triger OnRender or invalidate marker graphics?
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(Image, LocalPosition);
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a timer directly in the Marker class as it deals with the GDI which render the marker image from OnRender method every map interaction.

So you can remove the timer from the Marker class and set the image property for the marker from the Main form which the GMapControl is placed.

I create a demo project for you that demonstrate my answer:
Note: The used images i got them from google, so you can use any image or you can use 2 images (Black, White) and swap between them to make the blinking effect.

**You can freely download the demo project from the following link:**

**[Download Demo Project](https://app.box.com/s/zsbfmne8rlmjx4qapz8m8qvi7gvnfmlp)**

[image: **The final result:**]

**GMarkerNode.vb:**

```
Imports GMap.NET
Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms

Public Class GMarkerNode
    Inherits GMapMarker

    Public Property Image() As Image

    Public Sub New(ByVal p As PointLatLng, ByVal image1  As Image)
        MyBase.New(p)
        Me.Image=image1
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnRender(ByVal g As Graphics)
        if me.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            g.DrawImage(me.Image, LocalPosition)
        End If          
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Dispose()
        MyBase.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form1.vb:**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports GMap.NET
Imports GMap.NET.MapProviders
Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms

Public Class Form1
    Private m_Index As Integer=1
    Private m_ImagePath As String=""
    Private m_ActiveMarker As GMarkerNode
    Private m_ActiveImage As Image
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        with GMapControl1
            .Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache
            .CacheLocation = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"cache")
            .MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap
            .Position = new PointLatLng(30.050578, 31.223027)
            .Zoom = 15
            .Overlays.Add(new GMapOverlay("markersOverlay"))
            .Overlays(0).Markers.Add(new GMarkerNode(.Position,Pic.Image))
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Enabled=Not Timer1.Enabled
        Timer1.Interval= Math.Abs(CInt(IIf(IsNumeric(txtInterval.Text), txtInterval.Text,500)))
        If Timer1.Enabled Then
            Button1.Text="Stop"
        else    
            Button1.Text="Start"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        m_ImagePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"images",String.Format("black{0:D2}.png",m_Index))
        if File.Exists(m_ImagePath) Then
            m_ActiveImage = Image.FromFile(m_ImagePath)
            Pic.Image =m_ActiveImage

            '   Update the marker image
            m_ActiveMarker = GMapControl1.Overlays(0).Markers(0)
            m_ActiveMarker.Image = Pic.Image

            '   Update the marker in the overlay
            GMapControl1.Overlays(0).Markers(0) = m_ActiveMarker 
        End If
        If m_Index<100 Then
            m_Index += 1
        Else 
            m_Index = 1
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form1.Designer.vb:**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.GMapControl1 = New GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl()
        Me.SplitContainer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer()
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Pic = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.txtInterval = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        CType(Me.SplitContainer1,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout
        Me.SplitContainer1.SuspendLayout
        CType(Me.Pic,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'GMapControl1
        '
        Me.GMapControl1.Bearing = 0!
        Me.GMapControl1.CanDragMap = true
        Me.GMapControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.GMapControl1.EmptyTileColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy
        Me.GMapControl1.GrayScaleMode = false
        Me.GMapControl1.HelperLineOption = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.HelperLineOptions.DontShow
        Me.GMapControl1.LevelsKeepInMemmory = 5
        Me.GMapControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.GMapControl1.MarkersEnabled = true
        Me.GMapControl1.MaxZoom = 20
        Me.GMapControl1.MinZoom = 2
        Me.GMapControl1.MouseWheelZoomEnabled = true
        Me.GMapControl1.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter
        Me.GMapControl1.Name = "GMapControl1"
        Me.GMapControl1.NegativeMode = false
        Me.GMapControl1.PolygonsEnabled = true
        Me.GMapControl1.RetryLoadTile = 0
        Me.GMapControl1.RoutesEnabled = true
        Me.GMapControl1.ScaleMode = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ScaleModes.[Integer]
        Me.GMapControl1.SelectedAreaFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(33,Byte),Integer), CType(CType(65,Byte),Integer), CType(CType(105,Byte),Integer), CType(CType(225,Byte),Integer))
        Me.GMapControl1.ShowTileGridLines = false
        Me.GMapControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(639, 556)
        Me.GMapControl1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.GMapControl1.Zoom = 0R
        '
        'SplitContainer1
        '
        Me.SplitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.SplitContainer1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Name = "SplitContainer1"
        '
        'SplitContainer1.Panel1
        '
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Pic)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.txtInterval)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        '
        'SplitContainer1.Panel2
        '
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.GMapControl1)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(816, 556)
        Me.SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 173
        Me.SplitContainer1.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.AutoSize = true
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(54, 31)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 13)
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 4
        Me.Label2.Text = "Active Image"
        '
        'Pic
        '
        Me.Pic.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Pic.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(52, 54)
        Me.Pic.Name = "Pic"
        Me.Pic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(72, 65)
        Me.Pic.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Pic.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Pic.TabStop = false
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = true
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 154)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(134, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 2
        Me.Label1.Text = "Time Interval (miliseconds)"
        '
        'txtInterval
        '
        Me.txtInterval.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(45, 172)
        Me.txtInterval.Name = "txtInterval"
        Me.txtInterval.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(83, 20)
        Me.txtInterval.TabIndex = 1
        Me.txtInterval.Text = "500"
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(33, 211)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(107, 29)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Start"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 1000
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(816, 556)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.SplitContainer1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout
        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false)
        CType(Me.SplitContainer1,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit
        Me.SplitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false)
        CType(Me.Pic,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)

End Sub

    Friend WithEvents GMapControl1 As GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl
    Friend WithEvents SplitContainer1 As SplitContainer
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As Label
    Friend WithEvents Pic As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
    Friend WithEvents txtInterval As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
End Class
```